# Какую IDE использовать для написания приложения под Android?

Tags: android, ide

Для начинающего, мало знакомого с Java и Linux, программиста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы только начинаете писать под Android, есть смысл воспользоваться Eclipse, потому что под него есть соответствующий плагин, который существенно облегчает первоначальное ознакомление.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать и ИДЕЮ, но только ULTIMATE EDITION. Там тоже есть плагин.

Comment: Теперь уже нет: IDEA 10 Community Edition содержит плагин для андроид.

Answer (score 0):

Если пишешь под андроид, то ничего лучше всего использовать Android Studio.

Android Studio, основанная на программном обеспечении IntelliJ IDEA от компании JetBrains, **официальное** средство разработки Android приложений.

Comment: `то ничего лучше всего использовать` наверное лучше как-то по-другому сформулировать...либо `то лучше всего использовать`, либо  `то нет ничего лучше Android Studio`...как-то не по-русски получается